# Build Failed While creating package .pkg file

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, dmg, pkg-file

I am creating a .pkg file using “Packages” application.
 Previously I would able to create .pkg file with certificate also but  now this give me Build Failed error. while If I remove certificate than I can Build .pkg.
Even I am not able to get any error log for error message. If anyone has any better tool or method to create package file and dmg file please tell me.

[image]

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the cause of this error.
Problem was in my keychain, since I updated my **OS to 10.12.3** I was facing this issue. so to resolve this I checked out my keychain where I found my Installer certificate in **“Login”** part (see image1)

**image 1:**
[image]

so I copy this certificate in System part also (see image 2). All problem goes away, If any time I face this issue again I check keychain again. Problem solved.

**image 2:**[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that signing with Packages presently does not work well.  I think there is something in the manual about that, in fact.  I build my package with Packages first, then sign it with `productsign --sign <sign-id> <src-path> <dst-path>`.  The `<sign-id>` should be your "Developer ID Installer" identity, I think.  This has been working well for me.  You can then verify that the signing worked using `spctl -a -v --type install <path>`, where `<path>` is the path to the signed package made by `productsign`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /location to app
productbuild --component "appname.app" /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Company Name Private Limited" --product "appname.app/Contents/Info.plist" "appname.pkg"
```

> Try **PackageMaker** application; it is good.

**Use above command on terminal and your pkg will be good to go.**